# Magento 2: How to truncate companies table

Tags: database, magento2-b2b

I want truncate all tables of companies in Magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Note] : Please take database backup prior to executing these queries.

To truncate all tables of company magento 2 B2B

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `company`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_advanced_customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_credit`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_credit_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_order_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_permissions`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_roles`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_structure`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_team`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `company_user_roles`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `negotiable_quote_company_config`;
```